# How to cut string while reading from file in python

Tags: python-3.x

In a file I have below values in file, it can comma seperated or space seperated file

New1 String /log/home

Old1 Str /var/home

Abc xyz /aa/bb

Using program in python3 I need grep any line and any character, like line 2, second character that is 'Str'.

I tried with below code.
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")

h = f.readline()
print(h[:6])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
h = f.readline()
words = h.split() // split h into words (words are separated by space by default)
print(h[1]) // second word of the line (first has index 0)
```